# On recycle some applications get this error: Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, recycle

For some reason, after recycle, some applications keeps throwing the error below:

```
Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
```

What is it means ?

Comment: When you recycle, if there are any long-running tasks/threads they will eventually get aborted so that the process can restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means in your code somewhere a thread is being created that took longer than the shutdown timeout allows to finish its work. That thread had to be forcefully shut down and the way that forceful shutdown is done is via a Thread.Abort() call.

So check your code for infinite `while` loops or for `for` loops that have improper ending conditions. However this could just be caused by any slow code that takes more than 30 sec or so to finish its work.